# Errors with std list

Tags: c++, list, parameters, std

For some reason, I keep getting the following errors in ErrorHandler.h
why size function is missing arguments?

'std::list<_Ty>::size': function call missing argument list; use '&std::list<_Ty>::size' to create a pointer to member

```
    'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist> std::list<_Ty>::erase(std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>,std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>' 

    'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist> std::list<_Ty>::erase(std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>'


// in errorhandler.h

    class ErrorHandler{
        std::list<unsigned int> m_ErrorList;
    public:
        ErrorHandler(){ }
        ~ErrorHandler(){ }
        void ForceShutdown(){ free(&m_ErrorList); }
        void Add(int errCode){ m_ErrorList.push_back(errCode); }
        unsigned int GetLastError(){ if(m_ErrorList.size!=0)return m_ErrorList.back(); }
        void Remove(int pos){ if(m_ErrorList.size!=0)m_ErrorList.erase(pos); }
        void RemoveRange(int start,int end){ if(m_ErrorList.size!=0)m_ErrorList.erase(start,end); }

    };


// in criticalsection.h
    class CriticalSection{
        long m_nLockCount;
        long m_nThreadId;
        typedef CRITICAL_SECTION cs;
        cs m_tCS;
    public:
        CriticalSection(){
            ::InitializeCriticalSection(&m_tCS);
            m_nLockCount = 0;
            m_nThreadId = 0;
        }
        ~CriticalSection(){ ::DeleteCriticalSection(&m_tCS); }
        void Enter(){ ::EnterCriticalSection(&m_tCS);  }
        void Leave(){  ::LeaveCriticalSection(&m_tCS); }
        void Try();
    };
    class LockSection{
        CriticalSection* m_pCS;
        ErrorHandler * m_pErrorHandler;
    public:
        LockSection(CriticalSection* pCS,ErrorHandler* pErrorHandler){
            m_pCS = pCS;
            m_pErrorHandler = pErrorHandler;
            if(!m_pCS)m_pErrorHandler->Add(0x1AE1); // 0x1AE is code prefix for critical section header
            if(m_pCS)m_pCS->Enter();
        }
        ~LockSection(){
            if(!m_pCS)m_pErrorHandler->Add(0x1AE2);
            if(m_pCS)m_pCS->Leave();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/pop_back/
Nope, `pop_back` does not return the last element.  This is to prevent accidental errors.  You have to get the last element explicitly via `back()`.  This way is also faster if you want to pop several without reading them.  This also applies to all the other Standard C++ Library containers.

Judging by your warnings, it looks like you're also having trouble deleting.  For Lists it can be tricky:

```
void Remove(int pos){
    std::list<unsigned int>::const_iterator iter = m_ErrorList.begin();
    //no need to check the size, advance will throw an exception if pos is invalid
    std::advance(iter, pos);
    m_ErrorList.erase(iter);
}
```

Comment: `pop_back()` does not return the last element because it would have to do so by value, which could be inefficient—although C++11 move construction would ostensibly solve this.

Comment: @JonPurdy: It's not just about efficiency; it's about exception correctness. A pop that returns the object being popped will lose the object if the copy ctor throws an exception.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Another good thing to consider. Although, why a copy constructor would throw in the first place is a bit more concerning.

Comment: @JonPurdy: like `std::bad_alloc`?

Answer (score 0):

You use the list methods badly:

```
if(m_ErrorList.size!=0)
```

`size` is a method, so you need to call it (with parentheses):

```
if(m_ErrorList.size()!=0)
```

Note that `size` is slow for `list`; you may want to implement GetLastError like this:

```
unsigned int GetLastError(){ if(!m_ErrorList.empty())return m_ErrorList.back(); }
```

---

```
m_ErrorList.erase(pos);
```

erase takes an iterator, not an integer. Therefore, you'd better use

```
std::list::iterator it=m_ErrorList.begin();
std::advance(it, pos);
m_ErrorList.erase(it);
```

note that this isn't a particularly efficient way, either.

BTW, check that you need `list`; a `vector` might serve you better.

Comment: I don't think `std::list::iterator` overloads `operator+`.  I think he has to use `std::advance`

Comment: @MooingDuck: true. This makes the clumsiness even more apparent.